# Cypress: redirected page (keycloak) after Login is never shown in testbrowser

Tags: authentication, redirect, cypress, keycloak

I want to login on a page via  two-factor authentication  and keycloak-Server.
Login-process is working but the redirected page after login never shows up in testbrowser.

I tried a lot like cy.route(), cy.request(), cy.intercept(), but nothing seems to work.

Cypress-Code (nothing works):

```
import totp from "totp-generator";


describe('Test', () => {

it("Login on redirected page", () => {

    // keycloak login auth page (anonymized)
    cy.visit('https://XXXX/auth/realms/XXX/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=XXXXX&redirect_uri=XXX&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=XXXX')

    Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
        return false
    })

    const totp = require("totp-generator");
    const token = totp("XXXX");
    cy.log("-----------> totp-TOKEN: " + token);

    cy.get('#username', {log:false}).type('XXX', {force: true})
    cy.get('#password', {log:false}).type('XXX', {force: true})
    cy.get('#kc-login').click({force: true})
    
    //  two-factor authentication -> type in totp-Token  
    cy.get('#otp', {log:false}).type(token, {force: true})
    // click on Login-Button and eventually login
    cy.get('#kc-login').click({force: true}).then(() => {

        cy.url().as('currentURL')
        
        // original page before rerouting to keycloak Server
        // DOESN'T WORK  => Page is not shown in testbrowser
        cy.visit("https://XXX")

    }) // <---- END:  cy.get('#kc-login')

    cy.request({
        // page which is loaded in NORMAL Desktop-browser
        url: "https://XXX/REALM/#/XXX",
        method: 'GET'
    }).should((response) => {
        // Get list of All Users
        expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
    }).its('body')
        .then((response) => {

            cy.log('========= /#/XXX response = ' +  '' + JSON.stringify(response))

        })

    // call current rerouted URL via ALIAS 
    cy.get("@currentURL").then((myAliasValue) =>{
        cy.log("============> currentURL = " +  myAliasValue)
        cy.visit(myAliasValue)
        cy.request(myAliasValue)
            .should((response) => {
            }).its('body')
            .then((response) => {
               cy.log('========= currentURL response = ' +  '' + JSON.stringify(response))
            })
    })
})
})
```

Cypress-Log:

[image]

Cypress-Testbrowser:

[image]

Now I aks myself, wether its even possible to show a redirected page in Cypress-Testbrowsers?

Comment: Is there any update on this topic?

Comment: @fasswas any update! i am able to login but not redirected once logged in back